# What does "JA" stand for on this PCB?

Tags: pcb, circuits

I was trying to understand the circuit of my mechanical keyboard.

There was a point abbreviated as "**JA**" on the board.

What does JA stand for?

[image]

Comment: "Jack A", perhaps? Hard to say, might be company-specific.

Comment: Looks like a connector based on the silkscreen. Where does the PCB trace go to? It would help to know the context. It might be a debug or manufacturing test jumper or service jumper.

Comment: "J" is common for connectors and the "A" might mean "angled" as per a right angle connector.

Comment: Following the trace from JA-1 is not Possible for Me as it is a Double layered PCB And the trace Goes to the other side from here..I Cannot Access that Side cuz  then I have to desolder all Mechanical Switches from Board..

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't necessarily stand for anything. Markings like that are commonly used to indicate where a component goes on the PCB. Usually, the part is marked with some name, "JA-1" in this case, on the electrical schematic. This name is carried over to the PCB layout design as well so designers, layout people, assemblers, anyone working on the device knows what piece goes where.

Comment: Board also has other points marked as JA-2 ,JA-3,JA-4 and so on..So Does it Mean JA-1 Is Connected to JA-2 Or Some thing like that..?

Comment: Probably not.  For instance, J-1 and J-2 would be two separate connectors.

Comment: And "J" is a standard IEEE/ANSII reference designation for a the fixed - unmovable - part of connector.  It stand for "jack" (goes way back).